# how to generate this code mysql_fetch_array in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

how do I write mysql_fetch_array code in codeigniter

```
<?php 
$result = mysql_query("select * from tb_mhs");   
$jsArray = "var dtMhs = new Array();\n";
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {    
echo '<option value="' . $row['nim'] . '">' . $row['nim'] . '</option>';    
$jsArray .= "dtMhs['" . $row['nim'] . "'] = {nama:'" . addslashes($row['nama']) . 
"',jrsn:'".addslashes($row['jurusan'])."'};\n"; 
 }      
?>
```

Form Input :

```
 <td><input type="text" name="nm" id="nm"/></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="jrsn" id="jrsn"/></td>
```

Javascript :

```
    <script type="text/javascript">    
 <?php echo $jsArray; ?>
   function changeValue(nim) {
    document.getElementById('nm').value = dtMhs[nim].nama;
    document.getElementById('jrsn').value = dtMhs[nim].jrsn;  
 };  
</script>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? And how is this related to Javascript?

Comment: Your question is unclear

Comment: don't try to build a json string manually. Build a php array, then json_encode that.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return result as a array from the database, you can use something like this

```
// in application/config/autoload.php, make database available globally
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database');

// fetch the results from the database
$query = $this->db->get('tb_mhs'); // produces select * from tb_mhs
// get the result as a array
$result = $query->result_array();

// to do the other operations you were doing you can use a loop
foreach ($result as $key => $item) {
    // do stuff
}
```